# stable diffusion sometimes generates images with weird lines

Tags: line, huggingface, stable-diffusion

When I generate image with huggingface stable diffusion pipeline, it sometimes generate with weird green, yellow and red lines as shown in the picture.

Is anyone who knows the reason of this, and how I can remove this lines?

To reproduce :

```
model_id = "../stable-diffusion-2"   # I download stable-diffusion-2's weight and code
prompt = "best quality, extremely detailed"

scheduler = LMSDiscreteScheduler.from_pretrained(model_id, subfolder="scheduler")
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id, scheduler=scheduler, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
image = pipe(prompt).images[0]
```

[image: generated image from huggingface stable diffusion pipeline]